# What does "ListNode dummy{-1, head};" mean?

Tags: c++

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) { }
};
```

This is the definition of `ListNode`.  What does `ListNode dummy{-1, head};` mean?

Comment: That shouldn't compile. `ListNode` is not an aggregate (it has a user-provided constructor), so `dummy` can't be initialized using aggregate initialization, and it has no constructor with two parameters.

Comment: No, it's not. `ListNode` has a user-provided constructor so it's not an aggregate and doesn't qualify for aggregate initialization. Also, it has no initializer list constructor, and no constructor that can accept two arguments.

Comment: @nneonneo No it isn't.

Comment: @karllo what is your compiler?

Comment: @BrianBi: Yes, my bad, it has no constructor with two parameters. Somehow I misread five lines of C++, time to turn in my license.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's *list-initialisation*, a fairly new syntax for initialising objects introduced in C++11.

In this case, it's an error. Since the class has a user-provided constructor, it can only be initialised using a constructor; and this initialisation needs a constructor taking two arguments, which doesn't exist. If there were a suitable constructor, like

```
ListNode(int val, ListNode* next) : val(val), next(next) { }
```

then it would use that to initialise the object, passing the values `-1` and `head` as the constructor arguments.

If the class didn't declare a constructor (or only declared deleted or defaulted ones), making it an *aggregate*, then this would perform aggregate initialisation, initialising the first member `val` to `-1`, and the second member `next` to `head`. But it's not an aggregate, so this doesn't happen.

Comment: If this compiles, I'm assuming the specific compiler used allows something similar to aggregate initialization in this case, as an extension to the language. (It's legal to do this as long as it issues a warning.)

Comment: I feel bad for being this pedantic, but had the constructor been `ListNode() = default;`, it could be initialized without using the constructor. This constructor is not user-provided, so aggregate initialization could then be used, and aggregate initialization does not use the constructor.

Comment: @chris: Indeed. I've made the language more pedant-friendly, hopefully without obscuring the meaning too much.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I must say initialization is one of the things in C++ where it's so easy to underestimate the full complexity. I'm finding it tough to remember these points without looking them up, and even then, enough of them change from standard to standard (such as aggregate initialization being preferred over copy-initialization, which will probably change in C++17).

Answer (score 3):

This syntaxical construction

```
ListNode dummy{-1, head};
```

defines an object of type ListNode with name dummy and using braced init list as initializer.

The compiler searches a class constructor that has two parameters, There is no such constructor in the class definition  There is only constructor that has one parameter. SO the compiler will issue an error that it did not find an appropriate constructor.

I think you alread saw the following constructions

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

In fact this construction

```
ListNode dummy{-1, head};
```

is the same. You could write it as

```
ListNode dummy = {-1, head};
```

The difference is that class ListNode has user-defined constructors and as the result the compiler will search an appropriate constructor with two parameters in the class.

if the class had constructor

```
ListNode(int x, ListNode *node = nullptr ) : val(x), next(node) { }
```

instead of

```
ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) { }
```

then the code snippet would be compiled successfuly because this modified constructor would be called.